# The specified child already has a parent, removeView() on the child's parent first

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I post my question because i've read a lot of topics but no one has an good answer to my problem.

I use fragment with the sliding menu library for android.

this is my code :

My fragment

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (savedInstanceState != null)
        this.kaza = savedInstanceState.getString("kaza");

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_home, container, false);

    //Construction de l'ImageView
    FrameLayout frameLayout = (FrameLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.PhotoPrincipale);
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutparams=new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    frameLayout.setLayoutParams(layoutparams);
    ImageView v = new ImageView(getActivity());

    //Récupération des IDS des kazas
    try {
        ListsID = ReadData(context);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String iduser = (String) ListsID.get(0);
    String token = (String) ListsID.get(1);
    String idkaza = (String) ListsID.get(2);

    RecupPhotos(iduser, token, idkaza);

    for (int j = 0; j < URLBig.size(); j++) {
        new DownloadImageTask(v).execute(URLBig.get(j));
        frameLayout.addView(v,j);
    }

    return frameLayout;
}
```

my activity

```
public class FragmentChangeActivity extends BaseActivity {

private Fragment mContent;

public FragmentChangeActivity() {
    super(R.string.changing_fragments);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // set the Above View
    if (savedInstanceState != null)
        mContent = getSupportFragmentManager().getFragment(savedInstanceState, "mContent");
    if (mContent == null)
        mContent = new KazaFragment("Gambetta");    

    System.out.println(mContent);

    // set the Above View
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    getSupportFragmentManager()
    .beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.PhotoPrincipale, mContent)
    .commit();

    // set the Behind View
    setBehindContentView(R.layout.menu_frame);
    getSupportFragmentManager()
    .beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.menu_frame, new ColorMenuFragment())
    .commit();

    // customize the SlidingMenu
    getSlidingMenu().setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    getSupportFragmentManager().putFragment(outState, "mContent", mContent);
}

public void switchContent(Fragment fragment) {
    mContent = fragment;
    getSupportFragmentManager()
    .beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment)
    .commit();
    getSlidingMenu().showContent();
}
```

}

and my xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".HomeActivity" >

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/Actu"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:cropToPadding="false"
    android:src="@drawable/actu" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/PagePhotos"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@id/Actu"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:cropToPadding="false"
    android:src="@drawable/photos" />

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/PhotoPrincipale"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Actu"
    android:layout_margin="2dp"
    android:background="@drawable/shapeinscription"
    android:padding="2dp" />
```

So, i search to display 5 pictures one below one other in the FrameLaout "PhotoPrincipale"
but all the time the same error.

> The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first

I'm totally lost :(.

Thanks a lot for your help

> > 07-30 14:29:28.122: E/AndroidRuntime(7548): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> >     07-30 14:29:28.122: E/AndroidRuntime(7548):
> >     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
> >     ComponentInfo{com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu.example/com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu.example.fragments.FragmentChangeActivity}:
> >     java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a
> >     parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first. 07-30
> >     14:29:28.122: E/AndroidRuntime(7548): at
> >     android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2308)
> >     07-30 14:29:28.122: E/AndroidRuntime(7548): at
> >     android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2358)
> >     07-30 14:29:28.122: E/AndroidRuntime(7548): at
> >     android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:153) 07-30
> >     14:29:28.122: E/AndroidRuntime(7548): at
> >     android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1247)
> >     07-30 14:29:28.122: E/AndroidRuntime(7548): at
> >     android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 07-30
> >     14:29:28.122: E/AndroidRuntime(7548): at
> >     android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 07-30 14:29:28.122:
> >     E/AndroidRuntime(7548): at
> >     android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5227) 07-30
> >     14:29:28.122: E/AndroidRuntime(7548): at
> >     java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 07-30
> >     14:29:28.122: E/AndroidRuntime(7548): at
> >     java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 07-30 14:29:28.122:
> >     E/AndroidRuntime(7548): at
> >     com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
> >     07-30 14:29:28.122: E/AndroidRuntime(7548): at
> >     com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562) 07-30
> >     14:29:28.122: E/AndroidRuntime(7548): at
> >     dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 07-30 14:29:28.122:
> >     E/AndroidRuntime(7548): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException:
> >     The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView()
> >     on the child's parent first. 07-30 14:29:28.122:
> >     E/AndroidRuntime(7548): at
> >     android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:3339) 07-30
> >     14:29:28.122: E/AndroidRuntime(7548): at
> >     android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3210) 07-30
> >     14:29:28.122: E/AndroidRuntime(7548): at
> >     android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3155) 07-30
> >     14:29:28.122: E/AndroidRuntime(7548): at
> >     android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3131) 07-30
> >     14:29:28.122: E/AndroidRuntime(7548): at
> >     android.support.v4.app.NoSaveStateFrameLayout.wrap(NoSaveStateFrameLayout.java:40)
> >     07-30 14:29:28.122: E/AndroidRuntime(7548): at
> >     android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:874)
> >     07-30 14:29:28.122: E/AndroidRuntime(7548): at
> >     android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1080)
> >     07-30 14:29:28.122: E/AndroidRuntime(7548): at
> >     android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:622)
> >     07-30 14:29:28.122: E/AndroidRuntime(7548): at
> >     android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1416)
> >     07-30 14:29:28.122: E/AndroidRuntime(7548): at
> >     android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:505)
> >     07-30 14:29:28.122: E/AndroidRuntime(7548): at
> >     android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1164)
> >     07-30 14:29:28.122: E/AndroidRuntime(7548): at
> >     android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5114) 07-30
> >     14:29:28.122: E/AndroidRuntime(7548): at
> >     android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2271)

Comment: just as a tip for the future: use the code style for stacktraces and not the blockquote. It is better readable this way...

Answer (score 0):

you are adding `URLBig.size()` times the same ImageView. That's wrong as the exception suggests

```
for (int j = 0; j < URLBig.size(); j++) {
    ImageView v = new ImageView(getActivity());
    new DownloadImageTask(v).execute(URLBig.get(j));
    frameLayout.addView(v,j);
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help but it doesn't work more :( . However you are right, i have to generate an imageview for each j :D

Comment: sorry for my bad english . with your answer, the same error is generate.

Comment: post the compleate stacktrace

Comment: post FragmentChangeActivity, and delete the answer with the stacktrace

Comment: avoid post answer ! Edit your question

Comment: ho sorry it's changed

Answer (score 0):

Modify

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_home, container, false);
```

to

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_home, null, false);
```